# Can I set to ScrollBar a floating Step?

Tags: .net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a panel in witch I represent a timeline - 24 hours(`24 x 60 min = 1 440 min`).

I need to set my scroll bar's step to a minute. It's evident that minimum size of such a panel should be `1440` pixels.

Let's say the screen resolution on the client screen (width) is `1280`, so say panel container max size is 1280.
Now, if I want my step be a minute I need to set the step to the scrollbar's container to `1280 / 1440 = 0.(8)` - but it's impossible, cause the Step (myContainer.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange) is an `int` value...

Can I do something to this?

**EDIT**

Maybe 0.2 pixel per minute can be considered a inobservable error, but if my step will be 5 minutes, it will in reality be 4.(4)px but in scrollbar = 5, a step of 10 minutes will be = 8.(8)px : 10px. On a 800x600 screen the 10min step will be = 5.(5)px : 10px, so in each 2 clicks(20 min) I have 4 pixel error. This "delta" became visible.

Finally, this is a sample, that **DOES NOT work** - even if I arrive to make the scrollbar visible - strange scrollbar visibility is unpredictable... - I can't scroll all the VOLVO logo in 6 (60Maxim/10smallChange) steps...:

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S1eOPUlVvQI/AAAAAAAAC8M/ZFWDI_aaJxI/s800/panels.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S1eOPUlVvQI/AAAAAAAAC8M/ZFWDI_aaJxI/s800/panels.png)

Designer:

```
this.panel2.BackgroundImage =  ....Resources.volvo_logo;
this.panel2.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.AutoScroll = false;

        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 60;
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange = 10;

        panel1.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange = 10;
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;

        panel1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(panel1_Scroll);
    }

    void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Scroll: OldVal {0}, NewVal {1},  Orientation {2}, Type {3}", 
            e.OldValue, e.NewValue, e.ScrollOrientation, e.Type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ClientSize in pixels (1440) and leave the small change = 1. It will also be in pixels and will match your minutes.